# sql store procedure loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have company table contains id, name and I have contact table contains company id, firstname, contacttype (type = 40 (admin), type= 41 (user))

I want to create a temp table that would have row of: company name, firstname(Admin), firstname (user)
some records could have firstname(admin) some could have firstname(user) and some could have both

I  created code below not much, but I cant figure out how to do a loop to store the firstname(admin) and then loop in the same contact table to loop for firstame (user)

```
DECLARE @tempreport TABLE
(
    cName varchar(50), 
    cFirstAdmin varchar(50), 
    cFirstUser varchar(50)      
)


insert into @tempreport (cName, cFirstAdmin, cFirstUser)
select
      company.name 
from 
      company
```

--loop though contact table and store in first name (admin) where (contact.contacttype = 40)

--loop i think again though contact table and store in first name (user) where (contact.contacttype = 41)

please point me to the right place, or to a similar example,

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something in the lines of the following will do. I'm not totally sure about the column names, but you can adjust them accordingly.

```
SELECT
   company.name
  ,[admin].firstname AS FirstAdmin
  ,[user].firstname AS FirstUser
FROM company
LEFT JOIN contact [admin] ON [admin].companyid=company.id AND [admin].type=40
LEFT JOIN contact [user] ON [user].companyid=company.id AND [user].type=41
```

Comment: Thank you works, can you also show me how would you adjust so it grabs top 1 record from the contact table. e.g. if contactid has more then 1 users, now it would show both (multiple rows), how would I show the first one? thanks again!

Comment: And what do you mean with the first one? With the lowest contact.id for example?

Comment: top 1, or first one it finds.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this:

```
SELECT Admin.CompanyID, Admin.firstname, User.firstname  
INTO #tempreport
FROM  (Select contact.CompanyID, contact.firstname from contact.contacttype = 40) AS Admin
INNER JOIN (Select contact.CompanyID, contact.firstname from contact.contacttype = 41) AS User on User.CompanyID = Admin.CompanyID
```

Comment: The subselects are not valid SQL syntax: `from contact.contacttype = 40` will not work.

Comment: I picked it up from your own words. Change it to right name of the column in your contact table.

Comment: I believe you're missing my point: besides the fact that the column names could be different, you SYNTAX is incorrect. The 3rd and 4th line are just incorrect SQL.

Comment: Ok. Anyway I gave you an example so that you could have an idea about how to solve your problem. I didn't give an example for you to copy exactly.

Comment: Ok, totally puzzled now.. I did not ask the question as you can clearly see when you look at the usernames.